# Item Count using CAML Query in sharepoint

Tags: list, caml-query, item

I have retrieved item count for particular field values in my `list` using `CAML Query`. But when I try to add up all those counts it's not getting added, infact it is getting appended.

For example, my item count for the values Q1,Q2,Q3 and Q4 are 5 1 0 8 3. When I tried `var total=Q1+Q2+Q3+Q4`, it is displaying 51083. Can anybody tell whats happening?

Comment: add your code in question. May be some coding error.

Comment: Don' understand correctly.
as per your question you are adding strings try to change it to Integer or any appropriate data type.

Comment: It looks like your problem is a C# syntax one... you're concatenating string variables, and not additionning int variables... Please, share your code so we can better understand your point.

Comment: are you using C# ?

Answer (score 1):

Sample example:

```
var cnt ;
var a1 ='20'
var b1 ='30'
//Now if you add it, it will append as it is string
cnt = a1 + b1
"2030"
// you have to parse as int
cnt = parseInt(a1) + parseInt(b1)
50
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
var total= parseInt(Q1) + parseInt(Q2) + parseInt(Q3) + parseInt(Q4)
```

Convert your each variable into number/int format using `parseInt()`

Answer (score 0):

The return count value may be stored as a string variable, so convert that value to integer format by using parseInt( var ) or Number( var ).

Then add the values and get the total for that.